# how-to-handle-updates-in-the-right-way in react or signalr

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net-core, signalr, real-time

I have a tag in my system that shows the quantity of items of a particular product

Now I want when deleting or adding the COUNT item to be updated

Will it be easier for me to update the STATE or use real-time?

What is more correct to do?

I will note that this variable can be updated by several users

Comment: What I understand from your question, is whether you should poll the server at regular intervals, or have the server push updates on change. Can you describe the architecture?